# Casting Sql server varbinary to string array in java

Tags: java, sql

I have sql server 2008, Which has a column with datatype varbinary(255). This column store string array. For example,

```
  [123.wav,345.wav] and store as [Binary Data]
```

When I try the following code

```
  resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
                 while(resultSet.next()){

                     byte[] bytes = resultSet.getBytes("files");
                     String stringByte =new String(bytes) ;
                     /* 1 */System.out.println(resultSet.getString("files"));
                     /* 2 */System.out.println(resultSet.getBytes("files"));
                     /* 3 */System.out.println(stringByte); 
}
```

get the following output

```
1) ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B47020000787000000001740012 32303134303332303136343434362E776176

2) [B@67515d5c

3)  �� ur [Ljava.lang.String;��V��{G xp t 123.wavt  345.wav
```

My desire result is string array

[123.wav,345.wav]

Comment: Can you show us the code that stores it?

Comment: I use grails to store data into the database and the type column in domain class is the string[].